# IBM MQ Connection issue using c++

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I have tried to create application to connect IBM MQ using C++ in windows environment, but it returns 2012 reason code(MQRC_ENVIROMENT_ERROR) and mqconnection gets failed.
But I try to understand [developer documentation for RC2012](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=codes-2012-07dc-rc2012-mqrc-environment-error) but I did not understand the action that is needed to be taken. So please help me to get it resolved.

```
queuManager.disconnect();
queuManager.setChannelReference();
mqChannel.setHeartBeatInterval(1);
mqChannel.setChannelName("DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN");
if (strTransportType == "TCP")
    mqChannel.setTransportType(MQXPT_TCP);
mqChannel.setConnectionName("127.0.0.1(1414)");
if (!queuManager.setChannelReference(mqChannel))
   return;
queuManager.setName("QM1");
queuManager.setOpenOptions(MQOO_INQUIRE + MQCCSI_Q_MGR);
queuManager.setUserId("admin");
queuManager.setPassword("passw0rd");
if (queuManager.connect())
   LOG("Connected");
else
   LOG("Could't connect.", Reason code : " + queuManager.reasonCode());
```

Comment: Here is a more up-to-date version of the developer documentation for 2012 - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=codes-2012-07dc-rc2012-mqrc-environment-error - this lists a lot more possibilities for this reason code. Have a read through and see if any of these are your problem. It is hard for us to judge as you have not told us how this program is built. Also be aware that the C++ classes for IBM MQ are stabilised, and you should write new applications using the C API from C++.

Comment: Thanks Morag. This helps me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted. You should write an answer to your own question in order to help future people who do what you did.